# Infinite loop when streaming a .gz file from S3 using boto

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gzip, boto

I'm attempting to stream a .gz file from S3 using boto and iterate over the lines of the unzipped text file. Mysteriously, the loop never terminates; when the entire file has been read, the iteration restarts at the beginning of the file.

Let's say I create and upload an input file like the following:

```
> echo '{"key": "value"}' > foo.json
> gzip -9 foo.json
> aws s3 cp foo.json.gz s3://my-bucket/my-location/
```

and I run the following Python script:

```
import boto
import gzip

connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = connection.get_bucket('my-bucket')
key = bucket.get_key('my-location/foo.json.gz')
gz_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=key, mode='rb')
for line in gz_file:
    print(line)
```

The result is:

```
b'{"key": "value"}\n'
b'{"key": "value"}\n'
b'{"key": "value"}\n'
...forever...
```

Why is this happening? I think there must be something very basic that I am missing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, boto. The problem is that the read method redownloads the key if you call it after the key has been completely read once (compare the read and next methods to see the difference).

This isn't the cleanest way to do it, but it solves the problem:

```
import boto
import gzip

class ReadOnce(object):
    def __init__(self, k):
        self.key = k
        self.has_read_once = False

   def read(self, size=0):
       if self.has_read_once:
           return b''
       data = self.key.read(size)
       if not data:
           self.has_read_once = True
       return data

connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = connection.get_bucket('my-bucket')
key = ReadOnce(bucket.get_key('my-location/foo.json.gz'))
gz_file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=key, mode='rb')
for line in gz_file:
    print(line)
```

Comment: +1: this is brilliant. In fact, using your wrapper, I can read a pandas DataFrame directly from a compressed S3 object. Thanks!

Comment: Nice!  This applies equally well to CSV downloads, which for me were also exhibiting bizarre behavior like the end-of-file getting concatenated with the beginning.  Would love to know why boto does things this way - very big gotcha IMO

Comment: Also worth noting when running this solution as a context manager, I needed to implement a `close` function as well.  It just delegates `close` to `self.key.close()`.

Comment: Can we extend this solution to `boto3` to read a zip file in 10 MiB blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [zweiterlinde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6592/zweiterlinde) for the wonderful insight and [excellent answer provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30676494/758174).

I was looking for a solution to read a compressed S3 object directly into a Pandas DataFrame, and using his wrapper, it can be expressed in two lines:

```
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=ReadOnce(bucket.get_key('my/obj.tsv.gz')), mode='rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t')
```

Comment: Python isnt about "who can get `it` in the least amount of lines", go read the bible -> `python -m this`